# Congruent Equation Prove

Tags: congruences

I was trying to prove this equation
I did these but I don't know what to do next?!

$2^a-1\equiv 2^{a\ \bmod\ b}-1 \ \bmod\ (2^b -1)$

My solution:

$$ a = cb+r$$
$$ 2^{cb+r} \equiv 2^r (\bmod \ 2^b -1) $$
$$ 2^{cb} \equiv 1 (\bmod \ 2^b -1) $$ (in this line I should prove that $gcd(2^b-1,2^r)=1$

and I dont know what to do next!
any suggestions?

Comment: Just fot clarity, isn't the RHS $(2^{a \text{mod} b}-1)\text{mod} (2^b - 1)$?

Comment: for $a=12$ and $b=9$, I get $1023 \equiv 8 - 1 (mod 511)$. I'm fairly sure this isn't valid.

Comment: it is $2^a - 1$ not $2^{a-1}$
I know you can remove -1 from both side, but the question was this form!!

Comment: Can you check my second comment?

Comment: Yes that's Ok
$2^{12} -1 = 4095$
so $4095 \equiv 7\ (mod511)$ is ok!

Comment: you want to prove: $gcd(2^b−1,2^r)=1$? There's nothing to prove there, $2^b-1$ is an odd number and $2^r$ is an even number with no odd factors, so, their is gcd is 1. But I think, I didn't get how you would go ahead with that.

Comment: A part was proving what you said And then "and I dont know what to do next! " !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: $ 2^{cb} \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^b -1) $

${\left(2^b\right)}^c \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^b -1)$

$1^c \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^b -1)$

$1 \equiv 1 (mod \ 2^b -1)$